# Receiving 'The SSL connection could not be established' message when restoring packages after running docker-compose build

Tags: .net, docker, nuget

After running docker-compose build, everything runs fine until restore packages point, then I receive :

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
>       Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

It appeared to almost work once by pulling packages but shortly after fails and fails ever since. Everything works fine running docker-compose in Visual Studio, it just happens through CLI.

I have restarted docker, reinstalled docker, re-ran command multiple times, tried in different networks, spent days researching online, rebooted machine.

```
Step 8/17 : RUN dotnet restore src/Services/Identity/Identity.API/Identity.API.csproj
 ---> Running in f3d6d7f541e3
  Restoring packages for /src/src/Services/Identity/Identity.API/Identity.API.csproj...
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/serilog.aspnetcore/index.json'.
  The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
    Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.options.configurationextensions/index.json'.
  The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
    Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect/index.json'.
  The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
    Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication/index.json'.
  The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
    Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.logging/index.json'.
  The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
    Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors/index.json'.
  The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
    Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
```

Comment: Thanks Sven Hakvoort for the format improvement.

Comment: I am facing same problem, do anyone has any idea?

Comment: Try this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/64752544/7545475
It's helped me in similar problem

Comment: Can you share Dockerfile? What SDK are you using? Are you on linux or windows container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for not getting back to this issue. This is no longer appearing to be an issue it appears to have rectified by a reason I cannot quite recall however I suspect it was due to network connectivity with my Internet.