# Dotnet restore Docker fail

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

There is problem with Docker and command dotnet restore.
I have the docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AuthAPI/AuthAPI.csproj", "AuthAPI/"]
COPY ["CommonCoreLibrary/CommonCoreLibrary.csproj", "CommonCoreLibrary/"]
RUN dotnet restore "AuthAPI/AuthAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/AuthAPI"
RUN dotnet build "AuthAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "AuthAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
COPY /cert /root/.dotnet/https
ENTRYPOINT /wait && dotnet AuthAPI.dll
```

and docker compose file:

```
  authapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}authapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: AuthAPI/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - peopleapp
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: db:5432
      WAIT_HOSTS_TIMEOUT: 300
    ports:
      - "8002:443"
```

When I run command

```
docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" build
```

I have a error

```
Step 10/23 : RUN dotnet restore "AnalyticAPI/AnalyticAPI.csproj"
 ---> Running in 2d29e1367d51
  Determining projects to restore...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.300/NuGet.targets(128,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/src/AnalyticAPI/AnalyticAPI.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.300/NuGet.targets(128,5): error :   Connection refused [/src/AnalyticAPI/AnalyticAPI.csproj]
ERROR: Service 'analyticapi' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "AnalyticAPI/AnalyticAPI.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Sometimes it works fine. There are warning about Connection refused, but restoring is success.
I use Windows 10 + Hyper-V + Docker Desktop + Linux Containers + NET Core 3.1.

Comment: If you try to load this url from your browser: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json do you have the same connection refuse sometime? If it's the case, it could be a problem with your connection and/or the nuget CDN provider. Actually, if you are located in Portugal or Argentina, they have an issue: https://status.verizondigitalmedia.com/

Comment: no, loading from browser is successful.
Location is Russia

Comment: I had issues in connectivity with linux containers in windows 10 myself. If you want to make sure that it is connectivity, try to remove the SDK image. If it is connectivity it will not manage to download the images.

Comment: @SteliosGiakoumidis , try to delete all images and run docker-compose build. 
Pulling is success

Comment: Ok that means it is not connectivity, your docker deamon can properly connect to the internet.

Comment: @SteliosGiakoumidis , try execute 'curl https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json' in container. It returned json (success)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
It's works for me:

1. Add curl command to dockerfile before restore:

- **RUN curl https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -k**
- RUN dotnet restore "AuthAPI/AuthAPI.csproj"

2. Build image
3. Remove curl command from dockerfile
4. Build image again